# How to create the notion of binary tree in a database table?

Tags: android, algorithm, sqlite, binary-tree

I was discussing this issue with my friend and I don't understand the idea. Every tuple with this notion has a parent_id. However, I don't know how to traverse the table like a binary tree by using this attribute as reference. I am trying to model the bible in a database. The Bible is made of two contemporary spaces which are old and new testament which are linked to books. These are linked to chapters and chapters to passages. I want to be able to store a specific passage in a database with an url. Every url will be linked to sermons and explanations. I was planning to create one table for each class, so the schema would look like this.

```
contemporaryspace(ID int,oldornew string)  
books(ID int,whichbook string)  
chapters(ID int,which_chapter string)  
passages(ID int,which_passage string)
```

I am totally new to databases and was planning to do that; however, a friend told me that it's a bad idea and it's better to turn just one table into a binary tree to fulfill my goals.

Comment: The tag `sql` is not enough... Futhermore your question might be clear for you, but it isn't for an external. Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41818528/edit) and add appropriate tags (RDBMS incl. version) and provide more details, best is a sample scenario and a *clear question*. Otherwise this will be closed soon...

Comment: SO-police is working very fast and merciless :-) But you edited your question and provided more details. I voted to re-open already, but: Please add the RDBMS you want to use. Especially hierachical data is handled quite differently...

Comment: Hey, this is going to be funny :-) No, you should not add the tag `rdbms` but the actual SQL system you want to use (MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, whatever...) And please add the version!

Comment: Hierarchical data?. If you can , can you provide an explanation of what I have to study to fulfill my goals?

Comment: With `android` and `sqllite` I'm out, but others will rush in to help you... Just one word in short: A database consists of related tables in most cases. I'd clearly suggest to stick with your own idea. The binary tree is needed, if you do not know the depth and/or if the nodes of one level are not of the same type. But in this case you have a clear `1:n`-relation between each level and its children. Just add FK-IDs to your tables to refer to the parent row.

Comment: "Binary tree" or "foreign keys" ? You should ask your friend what they meant

Comment: Anyway, I might suggest learning a bit about the mechanics of said database (SQLite) independently of any app before you try to create one there. Secondly, if you want "trees", relational databases are poor choices when graph databases exist.

Comment: My input is that no you don't want to put everything into one table. Look up with the concept of normalization.

Answer (score 0):

If one parent has fewer or more than two children, the tree is not binary.

If any entries in your database are handled differently from other entries, then they have distinct types and should go into separate tables.
For example, if a book can have an author, but not a chapter, then you should not store information about books and chapters in the same table.

However, it's possible that not all tables are actually needed. Books have an attribute that specifies whether they are in the OT or NT, which would be a foreign key referencing the `contemporaryspace` table, but if `contemporaryspace` does not actually store any useful information, then you do not need that table, and you can store `"OT"` or `"NT"` directly in the books table.